# Update property of an Observable object (Angular)

Tags: angular, observable

I'm about to ask a probably dummy question, but I really have issues with Observables, so I try.
I have an object which I want to be an Observable. Let's assume that the Object is of kind example like this :

```
export class Example {
  public property1: string;
  public property2: string;
}
```

In a component.ts I have something like this :

```
export class Component {
  public myExample: Observable<Example>;

  constructor(){}

  myFunction() {
    this._translateService.service
     .get('SOMETHING')
     .subscribe(response => 
       myExample.property1 = response);
  }
}
```

The _translateService is returning an Observable.

This example is not working. How can I implement something to reproduce this behavior ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `map` operator :

```
export class Component {
  public myExample: Observable<Example>;

  constructor(){}

  myFunction() {
    this.myExample = this._translateService.service
     .get('SOMETHING')
     .map(response => {
          let example = new Example();
          example.property1 = response;
          return example
      })

}
```

Comment: Hi @Safiyya thanks for taking time for answering this. But your solution doesn't seems to work. The `myExample.property1` is not reachable in that way.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to create a new Example before assigning property, updated answer now

Comment: I got your point there. But at this point the variable `myExample` has not been modified in any way. The `let example` variable is not Observable.

Comment: Maybe i dont understand your question ... do you want to take an Example and the Service, smash them together and get a Example observable as a result that you can subscribe to?

Comment: Oups. I hope you won't be crossed with me... I misreaded your answer and miss the `this.myExample = ` part of it. Your answer is good and working :-)

Comment: And after another search I found an other way to do that. I'll post it as another answer to that question to help anyone else looking for that kind of solutions.

Comment: Glad it helped!